# pasar una variable GET php por AJAX para trabajarla en otro php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, mvc

Les platico como tengo mi estructura:

Tengo un *php* que se llama **crear_cajas.php**. En este abro una caja para poder después abrir un punto de venta (se crea una tabla con las cajas abiertas) luego al abrir el punto de venta, que esta en otro archivo php (que se llama **punto_de_venta.php**). Y ese punto de venta me muestra los productos de la sucursal en la que se abrió la caja, pero yo paso esta variable por la url y la recibo con **GET** en **punto_de_venta.php** mediante:

```php
$item = $_GET['sucursal'] ;
```

pero aqui es donde viene mi problema. Yo *modifiqué* la forma en la que se crean las *tablas html* con la información de la *base de datos*. Lo hago por medio del plugin de *Jquery* **Datatable** por lo que ya no tengo el cuerpo de mi tabla en el *html*, ahora lo hago con *ajax* (se ve asi):

```javascript
    var sucursal = $('#valorSucursal').val();
$('.Tabla_Productos').DataTable({
    "ajax": "ajax/datatable-productos.ajax.php",
    "deferRender": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true,        
    "data": {
        "sucursal": sucursal
    },    
     "language": {

            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "Último",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }

    }
});
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo pasar la variable

```php
$item = $_GET['sucursal'] ;
```

por mi *ajax* a mi otro *php* (**datatable-productos.ajax.php**) para poder trabajar allá la sentencia *SQL*:

```php
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE sucursal = '$item' ");
```

ya que este *php* **no esta recibiendo la variable** que se pasa al **punto_de_venta.php**.

También cabe mencionar que estoy usando **MVC** para mi *php*.

Comment: Tu pregunta es un poco confusa. ¿La petición Ajax debe usar ambos archivos: `datatable-productos.ajax.php` y `punto_de_venta.php`? Entonces haz la llamada a uno de esos archivos, y en ese archivo incluye el otro para solicitar/procesar los datos propios del mismo. El archivo que pones en la petición Ajax te sirve como punto de entrada al servidor y una vez allí, puedes incluir todos los archivos PHP que necesites.

Comment: ¿No puedes usar `data` de datatables para enviar esa información?  Míra aquí si te sirve:  https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Comment: @A.Cedano perfecto entiendo entonces para poder hacer uso de esa variable `$item = $_GET['sucursal'] ;` tengo que hacer un **require** o un **include** dentro de datatable-productos.ajax.php ? también debería hacerla global en punto_de_venta.php?

Comment: No exactamente. Es preciso entender que en `$_GET`  tú tendrás los datos que hayas recibido desde Ajax, en el archivo que indicaste en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax. ¿Queda claro eso? Luego, en ese archivo, tú recibes los datos: `$_GET['sucursal']` o cualesquiera, todos los datos que te mandó el cliente desde Ajax. Y a partir de ahí usas esos datos. ¿Qué necesitas algo de otro archivo `.php`, pues lo incluyes, y si tienes que pasarle el valor que recibiste en `$_GET` se lo pasas. No sé si me explico. Debes tener claro esos conceptos, si no, te haces un lío inncesariamente.

Comment: La cuestión es simple: `{1. Ajax (cliente)}` -> `{2. PHP (servidor: el archivo que pusiste en el parámetro url de Ajax)}` -> `3. {¿Necesitas otros archivos PHP, los que sea? En (2) haces include o require de esos archivos}` ... No hay más misterio. Quizá tu confusión está en pensar que tienes que usar datos del `$_GET`  en (3) ... No, no y no. Los datos del `$_GET`  tú los recibes en (2), que es quien te comunica con Ajax (1), quien ha mandado los datos.

Comment: Lamento interrumpir, pero insisto que debe usar `data:` en su petición ajax usando datatables y alli pasarle el valor de GET como crea conveniente y así **datatable-productos.ajax.php** lo recibirá y procesará adecuadamente (repito el enlace de la sintaxis que debe usar:  https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data porque no lo está haciendo en el código de la pregunta)

Comment: Mi comentario anterior se refiere a peticiones Ajax tal cual, ahora bien, si se trata de bibliotecas particulares como DataTable, puede que @masterguru tenga razón, verifica lo que él te sugiere (no uso DataTable y no sé cómo funciona). No obstante, es importante que tengas claro que en peticiones Ajax normales, si tú quieres usar más de un archivo PHP, debes incluir ese (esos) archivo(s) adicional(es) siempre desde el archivo que recibe la petición Ajax.

Comment: @A.Cedano mirate su otra pregunta relacionada y veras donde va a parar la petición y lo que pide ahora:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510690/como-usar-esta-variable-php-dentro-de-otro-php

Comment: @masterguru sí, es que OP habla todo el tiempo de dos archivos en el servidor (mi idea al leer la pregunta es que OP querría por ejemplo reutilizar código, incluir clases y cosas así). Adiel, si estás trabajando con DataTable, y la tabla **se crea del lado del servidor**, [revisa la documentación específica para ese caso](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) a fin de tener un código optimizado, pues el rendimiento podría estar comprometido si esperas muchas filas y no aplicas el código correcto para manejar ese tipo de situaciones.

Comment: De todos modos, @masterguru, en su otra pregunta OP muestra una clase, por tanto, si OP quiere utilizar esa clase para generar su tabla, debe hacer lo que he dicho en mi anterior comentario: dirigir la petición Ajax a un archivo PHP que cree la tabla. En ese archivo, OP puede instanciar la clase que genera la tabla, pasarle los parámetros que recibe desde el cliente y devolver la tabla generada. A no ser que haya otra forma propia de DataTable... no he leído la doc. ni conozco esa herramienta.

Comment: @masterguru edite el código del ajax como creo que sugeriste agregue el `data:` donde le aloje la variable **sucursal** que estoy trayendo de un input donde le puse el value que lo esta tomando con el GET `<input type="hidden" class="form-control mr-3" placeholder="" id="valorSucursal" value="<? echo $item ?>" readonly>`, pero ahora no entiendo como puedo usar ese data para darle el valor a mi `$item` en **datatable-productos.ajax.php**

Comment: @Adiel ya he puesto mi respuesta, compruébala y dinos si ha funcionado, y si es así no me lo agradezcas, simplemente aceptala, que es la forma de agradecer las cosas en este sitio. O haz ambas cosas, vamos, pero la importante es aceptar las respuestas correctas para que las preguntas no queden pendientes para siempre. Y deja de enviar preguntas sueltas con lo mismo, pues ahora veo otra más [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510730/enviar-una-variable-por-ajax-a-php-para-hacer-una-consulta-sql) de hace dos horas.  Si lo hubieras hecho todo en una ya lo tendriamos.

Comment: @A.Cedano debido a varias preguntas que he respondido sobre datatables, ya habia tenido que aprender un poco sobre esa herramienta, y sabia de sus posibilidades, por eso insistí en usarlas directamente en este caso, pues su función ajax es equivalente a la de jquery con algunas otras particularidades añadidas. Pero entiendo que le explicaras las peticiones ajax tal cual, claro, sin problema, pero dificilmente lo hubiera podido adaptar bien a datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia lo que has puesto en tu ajax por esto:

```javascript
<script>
var sucursal = $('#valorSucursal').val();
$('.Tabla_Productos').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "ajax/datatable-productos.ajax.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "data":  {
            "sucursal": sucursal
        }
    },
    "deferRender": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true,        
    "language": {
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Primero",
        "sLast":     "Último",
        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Y luego, en **datatable-productos.ajax.php** (cuyo código aparece en esta otra pregunta: [Como usar esta variable PHP dentro de otro PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/510690/263200)) agregas esto antes de llamar a la función `mostarTablaProductos()`:

```php
$item = $_POST['sucursal'];
```

y luego, al llamarla, lo haces pasándole el parámetro `$item`, es decir:

```php
$activarproductos -> mostarTablaProductos($item);
```

Y para terminar, cambia la definición de la función agregándole el parámetro nuevo, de esta forma:

```php
public function mostarTablaProductos($item)
```

Y diria que ya esta. Si no me he equivocado, que tambien puede ser, con eso has conseguido enviar el valor del `$item` correctamente entre distintos archivos php tal como pedias en tu pregunta.

**Explicación:**

Le hemos puesto correctamente la sintaxis a la llamada `ajax` de datatables, pues antes habias puesto esto:

```javascript
    "ajax": "ajax/datatable-productos.ajax.php",
    "deferRender": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true,        
    "data": {
        "sucursal": sucursal
    },
etc...
```

pero en realidad la sintaxis, tal como viene documentada [en su web](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data), era esta:

```javascript
    "ajax": {
        "url": "ajax/datatable-productos.ajax.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "data":  {
            "sucursal": sucursal
        }
    },
    "deferRender": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true,   
etc...
```

Con eso conseguimos que, al igual que *jquery*, tal como dice la propia documentación de [datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data), pasemos por POST la variable `sucursal`:

> In principle it operates in exactly the same way as jQuery's
> $.ajax.data property, in that it can be given as an object with
> parameters and values to submit,

que después, mirando el resto de código añadido en esta respuesta, recogemos con **POST** y lo aplicamos a la función `mostarTablaProductos` dentro del archivo **datatable-productos.ajax.php**.

Confio en que funcione, ya nos diras que tal.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la paciencia, me a funcionado aun sigo aprendiendo como usar ajax por eso tantas mis dudas.

Comment: Si, se entiende, y yo me he precipitado al pensar que la tercera pregunta era mas de lo mismo, alli tienes otro problema, no este, perdona.