# Enviar una variable por AJAX a PHP para hacer una consulta SQL

Tags: php, sql, ajax, php8

la forma en la que estoy tratando de enviara mi variable por AJAX es la siguiente:

```
var sucursal = $('#valorSucursal').val();
var url='../Modelos/productos.modelo.php';
console.log(sucursal);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:url,
    data:{'sucursal':sucursal},
    success: function() {
        alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
    }
});
```

y este seria mi pagina php de **productos.modelo.php**

```
<?php

require "Conexion.php";

 class ModeloProductos{

    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR PRODUCTOS
    =============================================*/
    

    static public function mdlMostrarProductos($tabla){
        
        $sucursal=$_POST['sucursal'];

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE sucursal = '$sucursal' ");

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();

    }
}
```

y al tratar de hacer esto me sale esta advertencia "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response." se que el problema es la **variable** por que al poner directamente el nombre de la sucursal `$sucursal='Nogalera';` si me lo toma correctamente así que debo de estar teniendo algo mal con mi ajax pero no se muy bien que es

Comment: @Adiel ponle esto al ajax **contentType: 'application/json',** es paradecirle que le mandas un tipo json. En el data le estas pasando el objeto entero lo tienes que serializar. `Json.stringify({'sucursal':sucursal});`

Comment: @JordiTurell le está pasando el valor del id `#valorSucursal`, no un objeto entero... eso aparentemente está bien... diria que el problema está en que no ha puesto todo el código relacionado, pues su error habla de `datatables` pero yo no veo nada de `datatables` en esta pregunta en si.

Comment: o quizas es que ha puesto `type: "POST"` pero en la documentacion de [jquery de ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) pone `method: "POST",` y no **type**

Comment: Hola Adiel. Estás errando gravemente en tu código. [En este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510610/pasar-una-variable-get-php-por-ajax-para-trabajarla-en-otro-php?noredirect=1#comment907635_510610) traté de explicarte la forma correcta de usar Ajax, que consiste en usar un archivo que haga de intermediario, y **ese archivo no debería nunca ser una clase de tu modelo de datos**, sino otro archivo que incluya y/o instancie tu clase y le pase los datos de Ajax. ¿Por qué? Porque la clase debe quedar independiente, si tú metes un `$_POST` dentro de tu clase la estás capando ...

Comment: ... pues podría haber contextos donde recibas los datos de otro modo, no necesariamente por `$_POST`, pero al tener a `$_POST` dentro de la clase ya la limitas a un solo contexto. Las clases deben ser pensadas como moldes para construir objetos de ese tipo, y la información que se use para construir instancias de esos objetos **puede venir de muchas fuentes, no solamente de un `$_POST`**. Si no comprendes el funcionamiento básico de Ajax, que traté de explicarte en aquel comentario, irás dando tumbos con tu código, y además estropeando tu modelo de datos, lo cual es una pena.

Answer (score 0):

Estás cometiendo un gravísimo error aquí:

```
    $sucursal=$_POST['sucursal'];
```

Y también aquí:

```
var url='../Modelos/productos.modelo.php';
```

Haciendo eso, estás capando tu modelo de datos, haciéndolo depender de peticiones vía Ajax.

Las clases del modelo de datos son **para construir objetos de ese tipo, sin importar de dónde vienen los datos** (de Ajax, de un archivo, de otro servidor, de una API, ¡incluso de esa misma consulta SQL, pues [con PDO puedes mapear los resultados de la consulta a una clase de tu modelo de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233095/29967)!, etc).

Si tú metes el `$_POST` dentro de la clase, ya no podrás usarla en ninguna otra parte.

Entonces, tú puedes tener un archivo (que llamaremos `ajax-request.php`) que hará de archivo intermediario entre cliente y servidor. Él será el que reciba los datos que pasas desde Ajax y llamará a quien tenga que llamar (en este caso la clase del modelo), le pasará los datos, recibirá la respuesta y la devolverá a Ajax.

En ese archivo (`ajax-request.php`)  o como quieras llamarle, puedes además gestionar varias peticiones Ajax, identificadas por claves... pero ese es otro asunto. Lo importante es que pienses a ese archivo como aquel que te conecta con el ámbito del servidor.

Los cambios, si aplicas esta forma serían:

#### 1. En el cliente (Ajax)

Vas a dirigir la petición al nuevo archivo, que deberás crear por supuesto. Aquí lo puse en una carpeta `Ajax`, tú ponlo donde mejor te convenga.

```
var sucursal = $('#valorSucursal').val();
var url='../Ajax/ajax-request.php';
console.log(sucursal);
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url:url,
    data:{'sucursal':sucursal},
    success: function() {
        alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
    }
});
```

#### 2. En el servidor (`ajax-request.php`)

```
/*
   Verificamos que el POST tiene los datos
*/
$sucursal=$_POST["sucursal"] ?? null;
if ($sucursal) {
    /*
       Aquí incluimos la clase, pero
       dado que el método es estático, no la instanciamos
    */
    include '../Modelos/productos.modelo.php';
    $table="AQUÍ-PON-EL-NOMBRE-DE-LA-TABLA";
    $mData=ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarProductosBySucursal($table,$sucursal);
} else {
    $mData=array('error'=>'No enviaste ninguna sucursal');
}
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($mData);
```

#### 3. En el servidor (tu clase, no capada, ni dependiente del contexto)

Voy a crear un método más apropiado. Y voy a implementar consultas preparadas.

```
 require "Conexion.php";

 class ModeloProductos{

    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR PRODUCTOS
    =============================================*/    

    static public function mdlMostrarProductosBySucursal($tabla, $sucursal){        
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE sucursal = :sucursal");
        $stmt->bindParam(':sucursal', $sucursal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> execute();
        return $stmt -> fetchAll();
    }
}
```

De este modo el código debería funcionar, y no habrás contaminado tu modelo de datos con elementos circunstanciales, como podrían ser datos que vienen de un `$_POST`.

Y, como dije antes, `ajax-request.php` podría emerger como un gestor de peticiones Ajax, haciendo siempre de intermediario. Imaginemos un CRUD por ejemplo, o una aplicación más amplia... poniendo claves adicionales en la petición, puedes decidir desde `ajax-request.php` qué otro archivo de PHP llamar, qué datos pasar, etc.

Si lo que debe hacer `ajax-request.php` tú lo esparces por todos lados, no solamente te perderás en el código, sino que estarás estropeando tu modelo de datos, teniendo clases que no servirán para fabricar objetos de ese tipo en contextos distintos.